# Starting Flask app from outside __init__.py from command line

Tags: python, flask

I have a very simple flask app that looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():

  app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
  app.config.from_object('config.settings')
  app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py', silent=True)

  @app.route('/')
  def home():
    return 'Hello World!'

  return app
```

In my `settings.py` file I have the following:

```
DEBUG      = True
SECRET_KEY = mysecretkey
FLASK_APP  = app
FLASK_ENV  = development
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
requirements.txt
.gitignore
app/
  -- __init__.py
  -- app.py
```

At first I had the app factory in `app.py`, and `flask run` didn't work, but it does if the app factory is in `__init__.py`.  I tried changing the `FLASK_APP` variable to `app:app` to note that it's in the `app.py` file but that didn't work either.

If I wanted, how could I arrange to run `create_app()` from `app.py`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `FLASK_APP` env variable to app:create_app since you create and return the app from this function.